# fliping between a console program and a graphics program java

Tags: java, graphics, console

I am attempting to write a simple program that simulates orbiting objects. The program starts out by asking the user for some variables, such as how many objects, there masses, velocities, initial positions, preferably all as a console program. Then once all the objects are established I would like for the program to pop over to a graphics program or some sort of java applet and just show the objects orbiting on the screen. All the math and animation stuff I can handle, I just don't know how to switch between console and graphics.

Comment: just create and show a JFrame

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can open a frame from a "console" application exactly the same way as from a GUI application.

For example:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.Console;

class Hello {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Console console = System.console();
        String name = console.readLine("What is your name? ");
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Hello "+name+"!");
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Hello!");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(label);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```